# How do I create an Image from a byte array?

Tags: java, image-processing, file-io, nullpointerexception

I want to be able to take the data of an image as an array, modify it, and then use that array to create a modified image. Here is what I attempted:

```
public class Blue {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        Robot robot = new Robot ();
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,d.width,d.height));
        int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        int[] newPixels = IntStream.range(0,pixels.length).parallel().filter(i ->{
            int p = pixels[i];
            // get red
            int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
            // get green
            int g = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
            // get blue
            int b = p & 0xff;
            return b >= 200;
        }).toArray();
        int[] output = new int[pixels.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<newPixels.length; i++) {
            output[newPixels[i]] = 0x0000FF;
        }
        File f = new File("Result.jpg");
        
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(output.length * 4);   
        for (int i = 0; i< output.length; i++) {
            byteBuffer.putInt(output[i]);
        }
        byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(stream);
        System.out.println(image1.getWidth());
        ImageIO.write(image1, "png", f);
    }
}
```

Here is how it works.

1. The robot takes a screen capture of the screen, which is then stored into a BufferedImage.
2. The data of the image is stored in an integer array
3. An int stream is used to select all pixel locations that correspond to sufficiently blue pixels
4. These blue pixels are placed in an array called output at the same locations they were taken from. However, the rest of the array has value 0.
5. A destination file for my modified image is created
6. I create a byte buffer that is 4 times the length of the output array, and data from the output array is placed in it.
7. I create a byte array from the buffer then create an input stream with it
8. Finally, I read the stream to create an Image from it
9. I use System.out.println() to print some data from the image to see if the image exists.

Step 9 is where the problem shows up.
I keep getting a NullPointerException, meaning that the image doesn't exist, it is null.
I don't understand what I did wrong.
I tried using ByteArrayInputStream instead of InputStream, but that doesn't work as well. Then, I thought that maybe the first couple of bytes encode the coding information for the image, so I tried copying that over to the output array, but that didn't solve the problem either. I am not sure why my byte array isn't turning into an image.

Comment: Modify step 4 to copy the pixel values back to `pixels` and clear all other indexes in the array. Then skip step 6, 7 and  8. Finally, modify step 9 to print and write your original image `img` that now contains your modified blue pixels.  
Much faster, probably simpler to reason about and hopefully correct.

Comment: (The reason your version doesn't work is because `ImageIO.read()` is for reading images in a defined file format, not reading pixels).

Comment: @HaraldK By clearing indices, you mean setting them to 0, correct?

Comment: @HaraldK Also, what do you mean by "write your original image"?

Comment: 1: Yes. Or perhaps `0xFF000000` if your image contains transparency. 2: By "your original image" I mean `img` (the screen capture). To write it, replace the last line with this: `ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);`.

Comment: @HaraldK I understand now, it is because arrays are a reference type, meaning that when you copy the image data into pixels, pixels becomes a reference that points to the image and thus can directly affect the image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo summarize the comments in an answer, the problem is that you have an array of "raw" pixels, and try to pass that to `ImageIO.read()`. `ImageIO.read()` reads images stored in a defined file format, like PNG, JPEG or TIFF (while the pixel array is just pixels, it does not contain information on image dimension, color model, compression etc.). If no plugin is found for the input, the method will return `null`(thus the `NullPointerException`).

To create a `BufferedImage` from the pixel array, you could create a raster around the array, pick a suitable color model and create a new `BufferedImage` using the constructor taking a `Raster` and `ColorModel` parameter. You can see how to do that in one of my other answers.

However, as you already *have* a `BufferedImage` and access to its pixels, it's much easier (and cheaper CPU/memory wise) to just reuse that.

You can replace your code with the following (see comments for details and relation to your steps):

```
public class Blue {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        // 1. Create screen capture
        Robot robot = new Robot ();
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, d.width, d.height));

        // 2: Get backing array
        int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        // 3: Find all "sufficiently blue" pixels
        int[] bluePixels = IntStream.range(0, pixels.length).parallel()
                              .filter(i -> pixels[i] & 0xff >= 200).toArray();

        // 4a: Clear all pixels to opaque black
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0xFF000000;
        }

        // 4b: Set all blue pixels to opaque blue
        for (int i = 0; i < bluePixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[bluePixels[i]] = 0xFF0000FF;
        }

        // 5: Make sure the file extension matches the file format for less confusion...  
        File f = new File("result.png");
        // 9: Print & write image (steps 6-8 is not needed)
        System.out.println(img);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have literally been working on this single problem for over 3 hours, maybe even 5. I've been looking all over StackOverflow and the Internet, and this is the only solution I can understand enough to implement myself. I'd upvote all your answers, but the last time I did that, I got a warning from SO moderation and got my votes removed. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Glad it helped!  And yes, "serial" down/up voting is discouraged. Just upvote whenever you find a question or answer helpful. Happy coding!